# calculate the latitude longitude range of a specified region

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am working in android `GoogleMap` project. I have the `Geo` position of the user (latitude and longitude) of the user. I want to calculate the co-ordinates the region with in 5 km (circle) of the user so that I can filter out the places from the database around the user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latitude and Longitude are in degrees so you need to use a simple flat earth projection.  **IMPORTANT:  all lat/lon values in the formula below should be in radians, not degrees!**  Using flat earth is adequate because your radius is 5km.  The flat earth projection is:

```
var R = 6371; // km
var x = (lon2-lon1) * Math.cos((lat1+lat2)/2);
var y = (lat2-lat1);
var d = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
```

Now lat1/lon1 is the reference position, in your case, the position of the user.  Lat2/lon2 would be the point your are testing. The variable 'd' is the distance.  Since 'R' is specified in km, then 'd' will be in km.

If 'd' is less the 5 (ie, less than 5km), the point is inside the circle.

Reference: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

The first answer (TreyA) appears to be showing you a stripped down version of the Haversine function. Below is JS code I give people that implements the Haversine function and converts the decimal values to radians.

```
// Convert Degress to Radians
function Deg2Rad( deg ) {
   return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

// Get Distance between two lat/lng points using the Haversine function
// First published by Roger Sinnott in Sky & Telescope magazine in 1984 (“Virtues of the Haversine”)
//
function Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)
{
    var R = 6372.8; // Earth Radius in Kilometers

    var dLat = Deg2Rad(lat2-lat1);  
    var dLon = Deg2Rad(lon2-lon1);  
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                    Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(Deg2Rad(lat2)) * 
                    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c; 

    // Return Distance in Kilometers
    return d;
}
```

Here's a link to a direct download of the file:
http://www.opengeocode.org/download/haversine/haversine.js

Comment: Haversine is overkill for a 5km radius.  Flat earth is an adequate approximation for this problem.

Comment: The formulae shown by TreyA is Pythagorean distance. It is an approximation (vs. Haversine) that assumes the earth is not curved. The rate of error in the calculation differs with longitude. It will have the least error at the Equator and greatest error at the North Pole.

Comment: I do not think Andrew's comment is correct.  The accuracy of the flat earth equations is not affected by the location on the earth, but by the distance from the reference point.  The farther you are from the chosen reference the less accurate the calculation.  Again, over a distance of 5km, the curvature of the earth is not significant in distance calculations.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, but as we move away from the equator the distance between a degree longitude shortens, further distorting the measurement. There is a good technical explanation at this previous stackexchange GIS posting: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58653/what-is-the-approximate-error-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-vs-haversine-formula-i

Comment: I believe you are assuming that the reference point is always at the equator/prime meridian.  But, the projection is created at the reference point lat1/lon1.  So, what you are saying is true if you choose your reference point to be the equator and you start calculating distances around NY.  I am saying you put your reference at NY and project out from there.

Comment: I chose 4 lat/lon point pairs on google earth: 1) 2 points near equator; 2) 2 points in NYC; 3) 2 points in Barrow, AK and 4) 2 points near Cape Horn.  The lat/lon pairs were about 5 km from each other.  Comparing Haversine and the flat earth projection, the 2 formula agree down to centimeters for distance.  For consistency, I used the same earth radius for both formula.

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain the point (in coordinate) of the circumference with:

> (x - x_o)^2 + (y - y_o)^2 = r^2

Where x_0 and y_0 are the coordinates of the user, r is the radius that you want to consider, and your points are x and y.

Because you have to compare the coordinates of the places with the coordinates of the circle, you can just put X and Y as the places coordinates and see if those solve the disequation:

> (X - x_o)^2 + (Y - y_o)^2 <= r^2

Comment: This will not work.  Latitude and longitude are in degrees and the radius is in km.

Comment: In Google Maps the coordinates are in double format, as a cartesian graph. R is not kilometers, is just a number indicating the radius of the circle, depending of the values of X and Y.

Comment: The coordinates may be in double format, but lat and lon are in units of degrees.  How would convert 5km to degrees?

Comment: I think that your solution (and the one from Andrew) makes a conversion. I consider both coordinates and radius in lat/long degrees, so you can use a standard function to do the "switch" considering the Earth as flat. Obviously your solution is more complete, because you do it within. I have a better image of the problem now, thanks.